# Carboys and dishwashers

Tags: sanitation, cleaning

I have this 15 Gallon stainless steel carboy, and cleaning it is always an adventure before I start my next fermentation.

As luck would have it, removing the to rack means my carboy fits EXACTLY in my dishwasher. Can I just run the dishwasher with the heat sanitize cycle and some starsan pbw in the soap tray (To clean before sanitizing)?

EDIT: After one of my responses (Be Careful with chlorine) I have a whole house filter, so I should not actually have any chlorine in the water for any of my pipes(Brine Filter, not reverse osmosis, so there are still nutrients no worries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but be careful with chlorine residues and products that are used.
However, it is always recommended to make the traditional cip.

Comment: Thanks! Added a comment to include my chlorine status.
With cip I am assuming you mean starsan rinse?

Comment: @flotolk Yes, can be starsan!! Thanks!